# Flutter: How to update data in Firestore using the previous state

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new in Flutter and I want to know if there is a way to update one field in Firestore using its previous state. I have like a `counter: 0` in my document, and I'm trying to increment it by one or decrement it by 2.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firestore has a specific operator for this called `FieldValue.increment()`

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value

```
var washingtonRef = db.collection('cities').doc('DC');

// Atomically increment the population of the city by 50.
washingtonRef.update({
    population: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(50)
});
```

If you want to decrement use a negative value:

```
FieldValue.increment(-50)
```

Comment: This is a pretty good solution for incrementing the value, but what if I need to decrement by 2 the value? I need to do that too

Comment: You can just do a negative increment for that. FieldValue.increment(-50)

Comment: Awesome!! Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

Had issues with making it work, syntax of the accepted answer didn't work for me, plus, after countless times of hot reload, it finally started to work with this code (I presume, should restart the app). Posting here, maybe it helps others because of slight syntax differences

```
  Future<void> updateStreakOnCorrect(String docId) async {
    DocumentReference collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("sentences").doc(docId);
    collection.update({"streak": FieldValue.increment(1)});
  }
```